# Maven dependency scope change from Compile to Provided not working

Tags: maven

I have a following dependency in maven pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.9.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Maven 3 build shows:

```
[DEBUG]    org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxb-provider:jar:3.0.9.Final:provided
[DEBUG]       com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.7:compile
```

According to the table in [Dependency Scope maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) the Compile scope in transitive dependency should change to Provided.

Can somebody explain why the scope of jaxb-impl is Compile (and it is added to the lib directory of a war module)?